# Create Django sphinx single page html?

Tags: django, django-sphinx

I created `sphinx` html using command `make html`.But i need a single page document with heading and content.When i click a particular heading page should automatically scroll down to that corresponding content.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `singlehtml` instead of `html`. See the [sphinx docs](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/invocation.html#invocation-of-sphinx-build) for all the build options.

```
make singlehtml
```